# How to programmatically search for an attribute in a Workflow\dialog, and replace it?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm attempting to be able to replace an attribute in CRM with another attribute.  Currently they are both option sets, but I need to be able to do this programatically.  I am able to download the forms for the entity, search for the attribute, and replace it with a different one, but I'm unsure how to do this in Workflows/Dialogs.  Anyone have any idea how to approach it?  Anyone have a working code example?

Comment: Hi Daryl, you mean to replace an attribute with another one with the same name? Or replace them on a form?

Comment: @Draiden Replace an attribute in a workflow with a different one on the entity.

Comment: Can you do it via parameter or did you already tried that way? You can pass a string parameter to a custom CWA, use late bound to change the name of the field that you are setting. Or you can use a configuration entity to pass a string parameter to the workflow.

Comment: I think that I misunderstood your problem because you are mentioning forms.

Comment: @Draiden, I'm wanting to update the workflow definition via SDK calls, replacing an existing attribute in the workflow, with a different attribute on the same entity

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of updating [Dialog's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334435.aspx) Taken from the SDK:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Demonstrates how to create, retrieve, update, and delete.
/// a dialog process.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// At run-time, you will be given the option to delete all the
/// database records created by this program.</remarks>
public class CRUDDialog
{
    #region Class Level Members

    private Guid _dialogId;        
    private OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy;

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Change the location and file name of the sample XAML file
    /// containing the dialog definition.
    /// e.g. Use the sample xml file located in the SDK\SampleCode\CS\Dialogs folder.
    /// </summary>
    String pathToXAML = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"CallCategorization.xml");

    #endregion Class Level Members

    #region How-To Sample Code
    /// <summary>
    /// This method first connects to the Organization service. Afterwards,
    /// create, retrieve, update, and delete operations are performed on a  
    /// dialog process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverConfig">Contains server connection information.</param>
    /// <param name="promptforDelete">When True, the user will be prompted to delete all
    /// created entities.</param>
    public void Run(ServerConnection.Configuration serverConfig, bool promptforDelete)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to the Organization service. 
            // The using statement assures that the service proxy will be properly disposed.
            using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, serverConfig.HomeRealmUri,serverConfig.Credentials, serverConfig.Device
            {
                // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

                CreateRequiredRecords();

                // Define an anonymous type to define the possible values for 
                // workflow category
                var WorkflowCategory = new
                {
                    Workflow = 0,
                    Dialog = 1
                };

                // Instantiate a Workflow object.
                // See the Entity Metadata topic in the SDK documentation to determine 
                // which attributes must be set for each entity.
                Workflow sampleDialog = new Workflow
                {
                    Category = new OptionSetValue((int)WorkflowCategory.Dialog),
                    Name = "Sample Dialog: Call Categorization",
                    PrimaryEntity = PhoneCall.EntityLogicalName,

                    //Language code for U.S. English
                    LanguageCode = 1033,
                    Xaml = File.ReadAllText(pathToXAML)
                };

                // Create a dialog record.
                _dialogId = _serviceProxy.Create(sampleDialog);
                Console.Write("{0} created,", sampleDialog.Name);

                // Activate the dialog.
                SetStateRequest activateRequest = new SetStateRequest
                {
                    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId),
                    State = new OptionSetValue((int)WorkflowState.Activated),
                    Status = new OptionSetValue(2)
                };
                _serviceProxy.Execute(activateRequest);
                Console.WriteLine(" and activated.");

                // Retrieve the dialog containing several of its attributes.
                ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet("name", "statecode", "statuscode");

                Workflow retrievedDialog = (Workflow)_serviceProxy.Retrieve(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId, cols);
                Console.Write("Retrieved,");

                // Update the dialog.
                // Deactivate the dialog before you can update it.
                SetStateRequest deactivateRequest = new SetStateRequest
                {
                    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId),
                    State = new OptionSetValue((int)WorkflowState.Draft),
                    Status = new OptionSetValue(1)

                };
                _serviceProxy.Execute(deactivateRequest);

                // Retrieve the dialog record again to get the unpublished 
                // instance in order to update.
                Workflow retrievedDialogDeactivated = (Workflow)_serviceProxy.Retrieve(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId, cols);

                // Update the dialog.
                retrievedDialogDeactivated.Name = "Updated Dialog: Call Categorization";
                _serviceProxy.Update(retrievedDialogDeactivated);

                Console.Write(" updated,");

                // Activate the dialog.
                SetStateRequest updateActivateRequest = new SetStateRequest
                {
                    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId),
                    State = new OptionSetValue((int)WorkflowState.Activated),
                    Status = new OptionSetValue(2)
                };
                _serviceProxy.Execute(updateActivateRequest);
                Console.WriteLine(" and activated again.");

                DeleteRequiredRecords(promptforDelete);
            }
        }

        // Catch any service fault exceptions that Microsoft Dynamics CRM throws.
        catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>)
        {
            // You can handle an exception here or pass it back to the calling method.
            throw;
        }
    } 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Edit:

```
 // Update the dialog.
                // Deactivate the dialog before you can update it.
                SetStateRequest deactivateRequest = new SetStateRequest
                {
                    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId),
                    State = new OptionSetValue((int)WorkflowState.Draft),
                    Status = new OptionSetValue(1)

                };
                _serviceProxy.Execute(deactivateRequest);

                // Retrieve the dialog record again to get the unpublished 
                // instance in order to update.
                Workflow retrievedDialogDeactivated = (Workflow)_serviceProxy.Retrieve(Workflow.EntityLogicalName, _dialogId, cols);

                // Update the dialog.
                retrievedDialogDeactivated.Name = "Updated Dialog: Call Categorization";
                _serviceProxy.Update(retrievedDialogDeactivated);

                Console.Write(" updated,");
```

While it is just updating the name of the Dialog, I am sure that it can be applied to any of the parts of that Dialog.

Comment: Looks like that is creating a dialog via XAML, but not updating it after it is created.  Is it possible to just do a search and replace in the xaml for the attribute to be replaced?